# How to merge 2 video URL's into one MP4 file with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, file, mp4

I am working in a new project where I get 1 or more URLs of MP4 files, so I want to merge them into one unique file. I saw that it can be done with some libraries, but they are using NodeJS, and I need to use vanilla JS.

I did not find any possible solution. I tried joining them:

```js
let newUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videos[activeVideo]);
myvid.src = newUrl;

console.log(myvid.src);

myvid.addEventListener('ended', async function(e) {
  myvid.pause();

  // update the new active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % videos.length;

  // update the video source and play
  let newUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videos[activeVideo]);
  myvid.src = newUrl;

  myvid.play();

  console.log(myvid.src);
});
```

Comment: There is no client-side solution that allows you to merge videos. Merging or splicing videos is non-trivial as it requires re-encoding the video, and it’s something that the browser’s JS engine is not designed to do efficiently. You should look into exploring server-side options or a service that allows you to do that.

Comment: Oh I understand, so the code that I provide is working but 50% of the times I get the error: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1039540190840111144/1066447883223703703/image.png

Comment: @Geloteee Your question is not clear. Merge means **combine** so how does your shown code try to create an MP4 as _"one unique file"_? All your code does is try to play (not merge) multiple videos in a `<video>` tag. Is that what you wanted (a sequence of videos in a tag)? Or you really want a result of one large MP4 file (combine bytes of multiple MP4 files as one file). For merging this means working with binary data and editing MP4 headers. Can you read/write hex values in JS? If not, then better for you to search for, convert other existing, or hire for an MP4 merging code written in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Client side code does not "merge" videos. If you want to play them after each other then your code seems too complex. This works - I have split the event handlers so the pause does not run into the play

```js
const videos = ["https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-5s.mp4",
  "https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-10s.mp4",
  "https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-15s.mp4"
];
const length = videos.length;
let activeVideo = 0;
const myvid = document.getElementById("myvid");
myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  activeVideo++;
  if (activeVideo >= length) return;
  myvid.pause();
  myvid.src = videos[activeVideo];
});
myvid.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(e) {
  if (activeVideo >= length) return;
  console.log(myvid.src);
  myvid.play()
})

myvid.src = videos[activeVideo];
```

```html
<video id="myvid" width="250" muted autoplay></video>
```

Comment: This works, but sometines I get this error: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1039540190840111144/1066447883223703703/image.png

Comment: Have a look - I split the event handlers

Comment: It doesn't work even in your code snippet :(

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and Firefox. The mp4s are really laggy, but that is not my script's fault

Comment: @Geloteee See if the update now works for you. Sometimes the browser will not autoplay videos unless `muted` is added to the video tag setup (or you must first click the play button as device user. Then future videos will have permission, as now given by user-click, to autoplay)..

Comment: @VC.One I have that on my mobile but not on my laptop. Also I got a script error on the mobile if I had controls and clicked the 10 sec skip